# product of large numbers

Tags: python, pandas, largenumber

I have two sets of numbers:

1. one is a "list" (tuple works too) of powers of 2 (1, 2, 4, etc),
   which I'll call Mult_array. I can successfully define this to
   have a length of 1485, for example, and I can examine the values, so
   that code is working. I have tried to work with them in various
   format. I can sum up all the values in these "lists" and see the
   result.
2. the second can be composed in many ways, but right now, it is a row in a dataframe (the dataframe is composed of 1485 columns and let's say 696 rows (just to be specific). The values are all 0/1

I want to compute the dot product of MultArray and the dataframe and store the result in a new column in the data frame.

```
mult_array2= [1 << i for i in range(BigCourseDF.shape[1])]
BigCourseDF["sortkey"]=BigCourseDF.dot(mult_array2)
```

When `range(BigCourseDF.shape[1])` is small (say 45), this code works as intended. But, with the `mult_array2` length of 1485, the second line here results in an error like OverflowError: int too big to convert. This is frustrating because the value that results should be less than the sum of the values of `mult_array2` (which is what would result if the entire dataframe has 1's as their values).

Appreciate your help, and I can give more context if needed.

Update: [csv file of BigCourseDF here](https:///www.dropbox.com/s/cjggdix1ztuix7x/BigCourseDF.csv?dl=0)

Comment: Can you post the array?

Comment: @AnnZen: Do you mean mult_array2 or BigCourseDF?

Comment: The one that caused the Overflow.

Comment: @AnnZen: I added a dropbox link to a csv of the BigCourseDF. This line: mult_array2= [1 << i for i in range(BigCourseDF.shape[1])] defines the other array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that your BigCourseDF row (the one with the ones and zeros) is of data type np.float64. If you do a matrix multiply with a python int (unlimited digits) array, the ints will be converted into 64-bit float, which will give a problem around 2**1024:

```
import numpy as np
bignums = [1<<10, 1<<100, 1<<1022, 1<<1023, 1<<1024]

ones_float = np.ones_like(bignums, dtype=np.float64)
ones_bigint = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1], dtype=object)
ones_int64 = np.array(ones_float, dtype=np.int64)

# this works fine
ones_bigint @ bignums

# this, too
ones_int64 @ bignums

# this gives an error
ones_float @ bignums
```

So you have to convert the DataFrame row to an int64 array like above, or the entire DataFrame using

```
BigCourseDF_int = BigCourseDF.astype('int64')
```

(thanks Mike Tomaino for suggesting to use int64).

Comment: This is the right answer. BigCourseDF contains float64 dtypes. However, you can convert more simply than that by using the DataFrame astype() method. `BigCourseDF = BigCourseDF.astype('int64')`

Comment: Wow - thank you both for helping. I got both methods to work. Please delete if ths is not how to thank you both.